# Selenium opens Google Chrome instead of Chromium on Mac

Tags: selenium, chromium

I'm trying to run a script with Python and Selenium opening a website on Chromium. I have both Google Chrome and Chromium installed.
When I run the script, Python/Selenium opens Google Chrome even though it specified the Chromium binary. Any help?

My code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.BinaryLocation='/Applications/Chromium.app/Contents/MacOS/Chromium'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'/Users/s/Downloads/chromedriver', options=options)

driver.get("https://google.com.ar")
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use `binary_location` instead of `BinaryLocation` in Python
So your code will be:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.binary_location='/Applications/Chromium.app/Contents/MacOS/Chromium'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'/Users/s/Downloads/chromedriver',
                          options=options)

driver.get("https://google.com.ar")
```